# ext4 FS image gets corrupted on first mount

Tags: mount, backup, ext4, dd, disk-image

I"m in the process of replacing my M.2 SSD with a new and larger one.  I want to save an image of my existing partitions before I take out my old SSD so that I can refer to it when setting up my new install and make sure I don't lose anything.  I only have one SSD slot in my machine so I can't use the SSD itself, so that's what the image files are for.

I thought this would be fairly straightforward, but I'm running into a weird problem.  The image creation appears to execute without a problem and I can loop-mount the image without a problem.  But after poking around the mounted filesystem for a bit, I get all sorts of errors, such as

```
"ls:  reading directory <directory> : Bad message"
```

I created the images with a simple dd command:

`dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p5 of=backup.img bs=64kb status=progress`

When they were finished being created, I checked the images without mounting them:

`fsck.ext4 backup.img`

which then reported that the image was clean.

I then mount the image:

`mount backup.img <mnt_pnt>`

I then do an 'ls -R' command, and I get the "bad message" error mentioned above.

If I then unmount the filesystem and run fsck again, it reports all sorts inode errors.

If I mount the actual partition directly, there are no errors and the files that were listed with the "Bad message" error have no error.

Base system is a Kubuntu 20.04.  I made sure to force an fsck on all partitions before beginning the backup.  Backups are being placed on a NAS drive mounted via CIFS.

Procedure above is being performed on a Kubuntu 21.20 Live USB system.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:  I've looked at CloneZilla and fsarchiver.  They seem to promise a lot, but my issue is that I don't want to -restore- these filesystems after I've imaged them.  I just want to be able to MOUNT them on a new, fresh ubuntu install and extract and files I need.  I tried CloneZilla's instructions for doing so (which they themselves state is a work-around hack) and it couldn't mount the image after I decompressed it.  fsarchiver I'm not sure about yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this:  I ended up using e2image to image the partitions instead of dd directly.  It appeared to make the images without any of the issues I listed in my question, and I could mount the images as a loopback device.

Comment: I might also mention that using rsync with the `-ax --numeric-ids` flags is a great tool: you can restore an entire Linux based OS using it, only having to update the `/etc/fstab` with new FS UUIDs and installing a bootloader (grub with chroot method). That saves a TON of space compared to disk images.